# Parsing python docstring from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, docstring

I need to parse docstring from several python files and I need to do this with Javascript.

I couldn't find any reference for this, any ideas?

EDIT: I'm working with Titanium SDK and jquery. PyDoc is not the solution that I'm looking for because I don't want to include some process on the middle of the javascript and the python source code.

EDIT 2: SOLVED - Titanium can use python and javascript at the same time, so I can use python to parse the docstring from the python files.

Comment: What sort of environment are you using? Why can't you use a small python programme to create the data you need, and read that into your javascript environment?

Comment: I have to do something in javascript, an interface, to read python scripts and display them with their parameters and documentation.

Comment: Right, but does your deployment platform not have python? Could you use a server to process the python? Can you at least reveal what javascript environment you will be using?

Comment: The ideal scenario is not to use something between javascript and python source code. I'm working with Titanium SDK with jquery. The idea is to create an interface that reads python files and shows the documentation, methods and parameters. does that make sense?

Comment: Please update your question. Also, do you realise that titanium claims to support python. Why not do the extraction in python?

Comment: Because I'm stupid and I thought that you have to build your entire project in python to use python. I just digged a little more on the Titanium documentation and I can use python. Thanks for this, sorry if you waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how the lexer of [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) works. That should give you some idea on how to proceed. There are some other syntax highlighters to study as well in case this doesn't fit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "hard" enforced docstring format, but as with most of Python, only a "best practice" document. See the following PEP for the specification of how to use Docstrings and what they are, along with many Links for followup reading:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

You can also try looking at [PyDoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html), which is used internally by Python to display Docstrings. It can output HTML, but even if that is not sufficient, you should be able to transfer the Python [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py) into JavaScript to write your own parser.

Comment: Yes, I knew about PyDoc, but I don't want to use a tool between javascript and python source code, but thanks for the info.